# Why does Nautilus hang while opening home folder?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

I have a Laptop Pentium dual core 2.16 GHz with 2 GB Ram while opening home folder or any other folder in that matter window becomes unresponsive.

I tried to reduce nice values of some processes in system monitor still problem exists. Due to this I can't open any file in any folder.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Comment: Do you have any smb mounted Windows Shares?  Maybe one is disconnected and Nautilus is hanging on the ~/.gvfs directory.

Comment: @Jeff Excellent guess, I had this happen and that was exactly it.  I had to `umount -f gvfs-fuse-daemon` as root and then reboot.  `ls` and `df` would also hang on the home folder, with the latter giving the error shown [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=447314) (seems common to more than Ubuntu).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that's a problem with nautilus, take a look on the /var/log/messages to see if you can find any good info.

other alternative is trying Nautilus Elementary, a nice replacement for nautilus, maybe it don't fall in the same problem, but I can't promise you that.

If the problem is on nautilus you can install nautilus elementary using the PPA @

```
ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
```

to install it throw the ppa, use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

hope it help.